# sftp O_RDONLY works fine but O_RDWR does not

Tags: go, sftp

I could read the file after using functions Open() or OpenFile(path, os.O_RDONLY), but I could not remove the file after it. So I tried to open the file with the write flag os.RDWR like below code to see if I can remove the file. However, using os.RDWR I couldn't even read the file. Could anyone explain it to me the reason why it would lead to this issue? I have got the error sftp: "Permission denied" (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED)
I have tried to see the permission code of the file, the file is -rwxrwxrwx.

```
import (github.com/pkg/sftp)

config = sftp.NewConfig(nil)
config.SetAcct("xxxxx","xxxxx")
config.SetDes("ip address", 1234)
config.Connect()

if file, err = config.Client.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR); err != nil {
        log.Println("Cannot open "+path+" , err:", err)
 }

if _, err = ioutil.ReadAll(file); err != nil {
        log.Println("Cannot read "+path+", err:", err)
}

file.Close()

err = config.Client.Remove(file)
if err != nil {
         log.Println("cannot remove file)
}
```

Problem solved:
found out that I had opened the file without closing it. And somehow the file is still opened by FreeSSHDService. That's why I could not remove the file.

Comment: What is the permissions of the directory the file is in? You have to have write permission in the directory.

Comment: @BurakSerdar drwxrwxrwx from the func Mode()

Comment: What is config.Client? Maybe you can post the relevant parts of it. Also, is the file a regular file?

Comment: @BurakSerder I posted it on the code section. config is from sftp package. The file is a binary file. Does it matter what file is it? I can read it read it if I use Open(), but I can't when I use OpenFile() with O_RDWR.

Comment: can you post what err is returning, fmt.println(err) and from that may be we can get some info

Comment: @cslrnr sftp: "Permission denied" (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED)

Comment: Okay I think there must be some way you need to check if the permission for ssh/sftp user to delete that or check if there is any spefic directory which ssh user cant remove

Comment: I tried chmod as well, it did not cause any error but the file mode did not change at all, do you know any reason to cause this?

Comment: I doubt it is a problem with the code. I would doublecheck the umask settings. Could well be an SELinux related permission issue as well.

Comment: You are using sftp. There is another layer of permissions on top of what the filesystem shows you. It sounds like the sftp server is giving you read-only access.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the file path instead you have provided file handler.

```
config.Client.Remove(pathTofile)
defer file.close()
```

Here is the reference https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/sftp#Client.Remove